# How to limit starting current of a SEPIC based LED driver?

Tags: high-voltage, current-limiting, led-driver, inrush-current, sepic

I have designed a SEPIC based LED driver which gives 60 V, 350 mA constant  output with a good power factor. It is connected with 220 V AC source.Then I have used full-wave rectifier.After rectification I have used SEPIC converter for desired output(60 V, 350 mA) with good P.F. But here I feel the problem of its high starting current in the SEPIC converter.The starting current through MOSFET and inductor L2 is very high (18 A). Steady state current of those branches are within 2 A. I want to make the circuit in hardware. How can I limit the starting current of those branches around 2A? For better understanding fig. is given below-[image: SEPIC based LED driver]

---

[image: sepic based LED driver]

Thanks. 18 A found in simulation.My requirements is to make an LED driver which is connected 22o Volts supply line and will deliver 350 mA constant current at 60 volts output voltage. I have used SEPIC converter here for step down the output voltage to 60 volts from 220 volts and to maintain a good power factor.  Here I am giving the circuit-

[![sepic based LED driver][3]][3]

Comment: 18 A in simulation or real life? How do you apply your PWM in the simulation? Also, feel is not an engineering term, _"But here I feel the problem of its high starting current"_. What are your requirements? What's the saturation current of L2? What are your design parameters? Also, you do not appear to have any isolation here. Are the entire contraption encapsulated from any end user?

Comment: Show the full circuit please.